# Filter rows with multiple conditions using two dataframes

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes that share an ID number column. I'd like to filter df1's rows based on two conditions: 1) it shares the ID with df2 and 2) it meets a condition in a column in df2.

I have this code:

```
filter = df1[df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID']) & (df2['section_name'] == 'Writing 1')]
```

Could something like this work? Or am I going about this improperly? The first half of this code works: I can match the ID columns and get expected output. When I add the second condition, it returns zero results, but there *are* cells with 'Writing 1' in a column called 'section_name' in df2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question:

- What you are doing will work (probably) but why are you making this hard.
- I will suggest you to merge your two dataframes based on the ID. And then it will be easier for you to write any conditions/filters that you want.

I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
filter = df1[df1['ID'].isin(df2[df2['section_name']=='Writing 1']['ID'])]
```